# How to use onchange with serializeArray in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a form with 3 select part and I tried to create an array with serializeArray. I want to use jquery ajax to post this array to my php file. But I don't want use submit. when I had just one select tag, I used this code

```
<form>
<select onchange="myfunction(str)">
        <option value="">num</option>
        <option value="123">123</option>
        <option value="133">133</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In my ajax code, I used `open("GET","myphpfile.php?q="+str,true)` and `send()` without jquery. but now I have 3 select tag and I don't know how too use `serializeArray()`(or `serialize()`) with jquery. 
this is my new form

```
<form>
    <select name="num1">
        <option value="">num1</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>
    <select name="num2">
        <option value="">num2</option>
        <option value="123">123</option>
        <option value="133">133</option>
    </select>
    <select name="num3">
         <option value="">num3</option>
         <option value="12345">12345</option>
         <option value="12346">12346</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

the second part of my question is how to write my php code to echo my array. I think it should be something like this

```
<?php
$myarr = array();
$myarr = $_GET["str"]//or $_POST['str']
echo $myarr[0];    
?>
```

Thanks a lot! and by the way, English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var arrayForm = $('form select').serializeArray();
```

and then

```
var paramForm = $.param(arrayForm);
```

like http://jsfiddle.net/LBKeQ/

then you can use

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async:true,
    cache: false,
    data: paramForm,
    success:function (data, textStatus) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    url:"myphpfile.php"
});
```

Comment: Thanks @inye, does this code work like onchange method?

Comment: ofcourse $("form select").bind("change", function() {
    var texto = jQuery.param($('form select').serializeArray());
    alert(texto);
});

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I get your question correctly, here is what you're trying to do:

**Hooking events on dynamically added fields**

```
$("form").on("change", "select", function() {
  var name = $(this).prop("name");

  console.log("Select-Name: " + name);
  // if you use the plugin I mentioned further down and you'll need to serialize
  // all fields already here, you can use the plugin's .fieldSerialize method
})
```

Get detailed information here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

**Serializing forms**

Easiest thing here would be to work with this jQuery Form-Plugin:
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Create a json-dataset with almost no effort like this:

```
$("form").ajaxForm({ 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data) { sendToServer(data); }
    });
```

**Working with the data in the backend**

The plugin also allows you to work on the server with the script you provided ($_POST["value"])